# Using reference and pointers in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a problem with my constructor , can't figure out why the constructor is not recognized , and why it recognize int& and not just int ?

I try to change spirit and multispirit member to reference instead of pointer but it doesn't work , any help is welcome , thanks !

```
class Player{
    public:
    int playerID;
    int teamPlayerID;
    int playerGamesPlayed;
    int ability;
    int cards;
    bool goalkeeper;
    const permutation_t* spirit;
    const permutation_t* multSpirit;
    Team* teamOfPlayer;

    public:
    Player(int playerID,int cards,int playerGamesPlayed,bool goalkeeper, permutation_t* spirit, permutation_t* multSpirit,int teamID,int ability):playerID(playerID),cards(cards),playerGamesPlayed(playerGamesPlayed),goalkeeper(goalkeeper),spirit(spirit),multSpirit(multSpirit),teamPlayerID(teamID),ability(ability){
      teamOfPlayer = NULL;
     }
```

The function :

```
StatusType world_cup_t::add_player(int playerId, int teamId,
                                           const permutation_t &spirit, int gamesPlayed,
                                           int ability, int cards, bool goalKeeper)
        {
            Player* addedPlayer = new Player(playerId,cards,gamesPlayed,goalKeeper,spirit,spirit,teamId,ability);
        }
```

The error :
[image]

Comment: It's a slightly misleading message – the problem is that you're passing `const permutation_t &` where the constructor expects `permutation_t *`. You need to spend some more time thinking about constness, ownership, and lifetime.

Comment: On  a side note, your seemingly random permutation of the arguments between `add_player` and `Player`'s constructor makes it more likely that you're going to make an error somewhere. Be systematic and consistent.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code ***must meet all requirements for a [mre]***. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: *"why it recognize int& and not just int"* -- because that is how you are calling the constructor. For the first parameter, you specified `playerId`, which is the name of an `int`. The type of the name of an int is `int&` (which can convert to `int` as needed). This is normal -- the compiler is avoiding assumptions. Focus on the types where the difference is more than just an `&` (i.e. don't worry about `X&` vs. `X`; focus on `const X&` vs. `X*`, for some type `X`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that the fourth parameter `spirit` of your constructor is of type `permutation_t*` and so it expects a pointer to a `permutation_t` but the type of the argument `spirit` as declared in the parameter of the member function `world_cup_t::add_player` is `const Permutation_t&`.

That is, *there is a mismatch in the types* of the fourth parameter of the constructor and the corresponding argument that you're passing to it.

To **solve** this error, we have to pass an argument that is either of the same type or convertible to parameter type.

Comment: Thanks , is it possible to convert the reference to a pointer and then assaign it to permutation_t* ?

Comment: @Elad Yes, you can use the `&` operator like `&spirit` to pass it as argument. But note then you'll have to take care of the `const`.

Comment: @Elad While it is possible to convert the two pointer members to references there is a side effect that you may well not expect. The copy constructor is automatically deleted. This can make things like putting, and manipulating your class objects in a vector rather messy. You can fix this by writing your own copy constructor as of c++20. Search for `std::construct_at`